# Bibtex does not produce reference correctly

Tags: bibtex, citing, ieeetran

I am writing a conference paper and have references naturally. The template for conference paper is `IEEEtran` and the references have to be generated with the `IEEEtran` bibliography style. My problem is with my last reference; all other references are generated correctly but this one.

I check and changed my reference.bib file several times nothing has changed. Finally, I decided to use biber as the reference generator. And voila!  Everything works as it should be. There are two problems with this solution : 1) conference does not want biber to be used. It consumes larger space compared to bibtex. 2) Depending on that I exceed the page number limit.

Just to show you what I am getting with bibtex :

[image: Incorrectly generated reference]

What is expected is (generated by biber) :

[image: Correctly generated reference]

So how am I supposed to generate this reference correctly? At the end of this text, you can find the bibtex entry for this.

Additionally, I generate the conf.pdf as :

1. pdflatex -iteraction=nonstopmode conf.tex
2. bibtex conf.aux
3. pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode conf.tex (repeat one more time)

I get no errors when compiling .tex file.

Could someone help ?

B.R.

```
@inproceedings{artetxe2017learning,
  title = {Learning bilingual word embeddings with (almost) no bilingual data},
  author = {Artetxe, Mikel and Labaka, Gorka and Agirre, Eneko},
  booktitle = {Proceedings of the 55th Annual Meeting of the Association for Computational Linguistics (Volume 1: Long Papers)},
  pages = {451--462},
  year = {2017}
}
```

Comment: the dash is by design, it means same author as the previous entry

Comment: Didn't know that. But how can I get the authors ? One of the reviewer wants to see the authors. He mentioned it very clearly :)

Comment: it's ieee's bibtex style and they implemented that by their choice, as an author you are not really supposed to change it

Comment: thank you. Just for curiosity is there a way ? Because sometimes reviewers can get really rude about things that they are not really sure about

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668076/is-shown-instead-of-author-name-in-overleaf-ieee-conference-template

Comment: only by using a different bibliography style or fake it by adding a zero space character or some such inside a name so it doesn't match (but I wouldn't do that)

Comment: You wrote in a comment, "One of the reviewer wants to see the authors [of entry 16]" Well, just inform the reviewer that all they have to do to see the authors of entry 16 is to look at entry 15. If the reviewer is unable to do so, you may want to inform the journal's editorial staff that they've appointed a seriously incompetent reviewer.

Comment: Off-topic: You needn't specify the extension `.tex` when running pdflatex or the extension `.aux` when running bibtex. I would also omit the option `-interaction=nonstopmode`. In short, running `pdflatex conf` and `bibtex conf` should be just fine.